# I was wondering if there was a way to prune a r data frame object

Tags: r, dataframe, memory

I am running out of memory in my r project and much of the memory problem deals with the storage of data in a date frame.  Is there a way to cut down on the memory that r uses for the data frame.  The reason I ask this question is because I stumbled upon a solution for this problem in Python but not in r.  Here is the python code that I saw.

```
def reduce_mem_usage_func(df):
"""
    iterate through all the columns of a dataframe and modify the data type
    to reduce memory usage.        
"""
start_mem = df.memory_usage().sum() / 1024**2
print('Memory usage of dataframe is {:.2f} MB'.format(start_mem))

for col in df.columns:
    col_type = df[col].dtype

    if col_type != object:
        c_min = df[col].min()
        c_max = df[col].max()
        if str(col_type)[:3] == 'int':
            if c_min > np.iinfo(np.int8).min and c_max < np.iinfo(np.int8).max:
                df[col] = df[col].astype(np.int8)
            elif c_min > np.iinfo(np.int16).min and c_max < np.iinfo(np.int16).max:
                df[col] = df[col].astype(np.int16)
            elif c_min > np.iinfo(np.int32).min and c_max < np.iinfo(np.int32).max:
                df[col] = df[col].astype(np.int32)
            elif c_min > np.iinfo(np.int64).min and c_max < np.iinfo(np.int64).max:
                df[col] = df[col].astype(np.int64)  
        else:
            if c_min > np.finfo(np.float16).min and c_max < np.finfo(np.float16).max:
                df[col] = df[col].astype(np.float16)
            elif c_min > np.finfo(np.float32).min and c_max < np.finfo(np.float32).max:
                df[col] = df[col].astype(np.float32)
            else:
                df[col] = df[col].astype(np.float64)

 end_mem = df.memory_usage().sum() / 1024**2
 print('Memory usage after optimization is: {:.2f} MB'.format(end_mem))
 print('Decreased by {:.1f}%'.format(100 * (start_mem - end_mem) / start_mem))
 return df
```

Comment: The biggest cause of running out of memory (in my experience) comes from continually changing the size of the object, which causes more memory to be allocated every time. [Circle 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54154675/i-was-wondering-if-there-was-a-way-to-prune-an-r-data-frame-object) of the R Inferno had a helpful explanation about this for me. Another good reference for learning more about this topic is Hadley's [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html) book.

Comment: Is it possible to do what you need to do on portions of the dataframe at a time? If so split the dataframe into a few files, then read in one file at a time work with a subset. Alternatively, can you do this in SQL? Install PostgreSQL and work with the on disk in a database rather than in RAM in R.

Comment: You likely will not be able to use the Python approach above, as that is making use of different sizes of numerical types, while base R has doubles (8 bytes) and integers (4 bytes) and that's it (unless you really want to work byte by byte, in which case look into the raw type).